# Add Payment To Sales Receipt

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I would like to add the credit card type to a Sales Receipt, however, I see no credit card information on the SR. Here is my code:

```
//Set Payment Detail in Header 
        Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.PaymentDetail qboSalesReceiptHeaderPaymentDetail = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.PaymentDetail();
        CreditCardPayment cc = new CreditCardPayment();
        cc.CreditChargeInfo = new CreditChargeInfo();
        //to do another credit card type
        cc.CreditChargeInfo.Type = CreditCardTypeEnum.OtherCreditCard;
        cc.CreditChargeInfo.TypeSpecified = true;
        qboSalesReceiptHeaderPaymentDetail.Item = cc;
        //qboSalesReceiptHeaderPaymentDetail.Item = new CashPayment { Desc = "Cash Payment Ref #" };
        qboSalesReceiptHeader.Detail = qboSalesReceiptHeaderPaymentDetail;

        //Set Header 
        qboSalesReceipt.Header = qboSalesReceiptHeader;
```

[image: Payment Method]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to the [documentation](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0400_QuickBooks_Online/SalesReceipt) you'll find that there's a field named:

```
PaymentMethodId
```

The PaymentMethodId should refer to an Id value from one of the [Payment Methods](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0400_QuickBooks_Online/PaymentMethod) in QuickBooks.

e.g. it's not a "credit card type" per se, it's a "payment method" that you're looking to specify (one of which might be a specific credit card type).